# Adding numbers between 0 and 100

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
int x = -1;
int y = 0;
while(x<100)
{
    x++;
    y+=x;
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

use a while loop to find the sum of all the integers from 0 to 100

I've tipped out this code and it gave me a number of 5050 I'm not sure if it is right.

Comment: you should verify it with pen and paper

Comment: sum of numbers up to `N` is `N * (N + 1) / 2` so the sum of the numbers up to 100 is 5050

Comment: Ah, but you didn't add 0!

Comment: At any rate, this seems to be off topic as it is about Math / Confirming the validity of a program...

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, `y` started at `0`, which got added. OP covered all bases there.

Comment: (It would be clearer if you used a standard `for` loop instead of the `while`.)

Comment: Zero was included -- it's y's initial state to which everything else is added. I'm sorta confused by why the querant couldn't compute the result manually, though.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - You're right -- I missed that he started with -1.

Comment: @keshlam - Ran out of fingers.

Comment: Gauss has been summing up these just by paper and pencil > 2 centuries ago. Now we have hard time writing a loop to do it.

Comment: Counting binary on fingers and toes would get him to 1024... yeah, still ran out.

Comment: @peter.petrov -- Gad!!  How many fingers did he have?

Comment: :) I didn't mean that but anyway, you got it.

Comment: (Sometimes we use the terms "manually" and "by hand" rather loosely in computing.)

Comment: It's about arithmetic not programming.

Comment: @keshlam, Add toes to reach 2,097,151. :)

Comment: @peter.petrov I thought Gauss did it in his head?

Comment: @ajb I don't know, actually I am not sure if it's a historical fact. :) Just wanted to illustrate some things.

Comment: BrianS -- right! And yes, peter.petrov, the point of the story about Gauss is that he noticed the shortcut formula and solved it in his head when it had been intended to be a long-addition exercise.

Comment: All I know about Gauss is that you'd want to sit near him in a physics test, since brilliance is inversely proportional to the square of the distance from the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula for the sum of the numbers from `0` to `n` is `n * (n + 1) / 2`. It is easy to prove by folding the sequence in half like so:

```
 0   1   2   3   4  ...
 n  n-1 n-2 n-3 n-4 ...
```

Observe that each pair adds up to `n`, and that there are `(n+1)/2` such pairs. [1]

Using the formula for `n=100` we get `100*101/2=5050`, so yes, your answer is correct.

Alternatively, you can get Wolfram Alpha to do the work for you: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+for+k+from+0+to+100

As far as your code is concerned, the algorithm can be expressed more explicitly with a `for` loop in place of the `while` (or you could just use the formula above and avoid loops altogether).

[1] Strictly, we'd have to treat odd and even `n` separately, but I am simplifying a bit.

Comment: My teacher is making me use while loops and not for loops

Comment: BTW, the print could be moved out of the loop if you don't need to see all the intermediate values. It'd also run faster that way, not that you'll notice the difference in this simple case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the answer is right. 0+1+2+...+100=5050